# Where to see Video Output of Droidcam in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, video, android, webcam, droidcam

I am submitting this question after searching a lot. So please help me.

So I have successfully installed Droidcam both on my Ubuntu 18.04 and android device.
I have connected both through USB cable run `adb devices` and device found.
Press connect on Droidcam client on PC side. It show no error.
I opened https://meet.jit.si/ in Firefox and hit run. It asked me permission to access droidcam for camera to share. I allowed. 
But It is just a black screen.
Output of `grep v4l2loopback_dc`

```
AAA@AAA-NCHS-series:~$ lsmod | grep v4l2loopback_dc
v4l2loopback_dc        24576  2
videodev              184320  3 v4l2loopback_dc
```

Please help what I need to do more. I just want to connect through USB only and not through Wifi. Further please also provide detail to see this video output in OBS studio. Thank You

Comment: similar problem. i am on ubuntu 20.04 (frequently updated). using droidcam client v1.7.1, and a samsung A10 with the droidcam 6.9.0 (dev47apps). it does work as a usb camera with zoom and messenger. but it is not seen by obs

Comment: yeah I am facing the same problem, I can't get the output on OBS studio ,so starting a bounty.